# Vector field of nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system

I'm working through a problem for a class I'm taking in Chaos and Non-Linear Systems and am stumped. How do I solve the following problem?

I am asked to sketch the vector field on the real line and sketch solutions of $x(t)$ for a variety of $x(0)$ of

$$x' = e^{-x} \sin (x)$$

I have no idea whether this should be done numerically or not. The problems have some that are indicated to be done numerically but this one is not.  Been attempting this for a while. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: So from my understand $x^*$ is just $n\pi$. Then the vector field is just dependent on the stability on the individual fixed points

Comment: Your approach sounds fine to me. Did you get stuck somewhere?

Comment: @rpa No I think I figured it out! Thanks though